# C#: Remove a specific items from the line

Tags: c#, replace

I am trying to add a if condition that if a particular word exist then I remove from the line.

For instance I have a string saved as: **Subject: Your Request - 5564 - 1345687974** then I want to remove Subject: and - 1345687974. I don't know if I am right but 
below is the way I am doing. Please let me know if it is right an

```
if (word == "Subject:*" && word == ^[0-9]*$)
{
    word = word.Replace("Subject:","");
    word = word.Replace("- "+ ^[0-9]*$,"");
}
```

**Note:**" " - 1345687974. contains at the end of the line and line also contains other numbers.

More Description:

If I have a random line after Subjet: how will I be able to remove by Subject: part and Regex part.

**Example**

```
 Subject: Your Request - 5564 - 1345687974
 Subject: Approval Message - 7798 - 1567643389
 Subject: New Updates - 15676433
 Subject: test0616_Subline 1234 -1345687974
```

Expected Output

```
Your Request - 5564
Approval Message - 7798
New Updates
test0616_Subline 1234
```

In first & second two example I would like to remove Suvject and number at the end with -
In third line I would to remove Subject and - 15676433

Comment: You are on the right track, but you need to use `Regex.Replace` from the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace, and use the `^[0-9]*$` as the pattern.

Comment: What do you want the final result to look like for your example?

Comment: @easymoney202  As a final result I want is Your Request - 5564 removing Subject: and - 1345687974

Comment: But one more question Regex.Replace can also remove - 5564 as well. Which I don't want it. What should be the solution for that.

Comment: Ok, well your regular expression should be (?:Subject: (Your Request \- \d+).*), then you can extract the Match 0 Group 1.  Look at https://regex101.com/ to test it out

Comment: var msg = Regex.Matches(str, @"(?:Subject: (Your Request \- \d+).*)")[0].Groups[1].Value;

Comment: Or, more simply, you could use Regex.Match(str, @"(Your Request \- \d+)").Value

Comment: any luck using the Regex?

Comment: One more question what if I have random sentence after **Subject: ** I will not be ablt to use above sentence which you added

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are given, and what you want as the result

Comment: @easymoney202 Please check my description.

Comment: I posted an answer with the solution

Answer (score 0):

There are methods of the string class that you may be able to use:

```
if (word.StartsWith("Subject") && word.EndsWith(" - 1345687974"))
{
    word = word.Replace("Subject: ", "").Replace(" - 1345687974", "");
}
```

Note that `string.Replace` replaces all occurrences of the replacement text. If that is a problem, look at `string.Remove`. See
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do?

```
String word= "Subject: Your Request - 5564 - 1345687974";
string pat = @"^(Subject)(.*)(- )([0-9]{8,12})$";

Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match m = r.Match(word);
if (m.Groups.Count == 5)
{
    word = word.Replace("Subject:", "");

    String numberInString = m.Groups[4].Value;
    word = word.Replace(numberInString, "");
}
```

This breaks up the string as a pattern existing of 4 groups. It checks for groups eq 5, since group 0 is always the string itself.

Each group can be specified using the regex pattern.
This would work for any number with a length between 8 and 12 digits.

Comment: Strange, I tried it myself and found no issue. Care to elaborate on what went wrong?

Comment: That's true, but you didn't ask for output either. Your question is not about how to output a string, it is about how to get the proper string. Anyways ... assuming a console app: You could try appending  Console.WriteLine(word); to see some result.

Comment: I mean output is not according as per expected. I only want is group 2 as an output. Regardless whether there is space or not before number. It gives output as: **Your Request - 5564 -**

Answer (score 0):

This covers all of your examples:

```
var lines = new string[] { "Subject: Your Request - 5564 - 1345687974", "Subject: Approval Message - 7798 - 1567643389", "Subject: New Updates - 15676433" };
var regex = @"Subject: (?<SUBJECT>[a-zA-Z ]*)(?: \- ) ?(?<ID>\d{4} )?";

for (int a = 0; a < lines.Length; a++)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(lines[a], regex);
    var subject = match.Groups["SUBJECT"].Value;
    var id = match.Groups["ID"].Value;

    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", subject, String.IsNullOrEmpty(id) ? "" : " - " + id);
}
Console.Read();
```

Produces:

Your Request - 5564

Approval Message - 7798

New Updates

Comment: <SUBJECT> and <ID> are labels for groups.  It makes it easier to find the groups instead of using indicies.

Comment: you did: Subject: test0616_Subline 1234 -1345687974.  Is there supposed to be a space after the '-'?  should it be '1234 - 1345687974'

Comment: The regular expression searches for [number]x4[space][dash][space][number]*.  If there is no space after the dash, i need to modify the regex

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I saw one comment don't know who added the comment but seems that person removed it. Well in my case after '-' space might come or might not  depends how input is made.

Comment: Well then it becomes more confusing.  You need to know what the separators are.   Is it always a -? What if there is a dash in the subject?

Comment: My solution answers your question. If there are other examples that don't work, please update your question

Comment: I did added the example. But what if I just want to remove last last Regex without checking that space exist or not. You can add as new answer